# probability of winning 2 tournaments out of three

Tags: probability

You participate in tournaments where each participant has the same odds of winning. For the first two tournaments, there are 4 participants. In the third one, there are 8 participants. What is the probability of winning exactly 2 tournaments.

My reasoning: For the first two tournaments, the odds of winning are ¼ and for the third tournament, the odds are ⅛. Where do I go from here?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming the odds of winning a tournament are independent, then the probability to win exactly two tournaments Is $$P(T_1\cap T_2\cap \overline T_3)+(T_1\cap \overline T_2\cap  T_3)+(\overline T_1\cap T_2\cap  T_3)=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot (1-p_3)+p_1\cdot (1-p_2)\cdot p_3+(1-p_1)\cdot p_2\cdot p_3,$$ $\textrm{with} \ p_1=p_2=\frac14, p_3=\frac18$

Comment: @callculus thank you so much !!

Comment: You´re welcome. I´m pleased that you could comprehend my comment.